# Using template variables in Django with django-compressor

Tags: django, coffeescript, django-templates, django-compressor

The problem is that `{{ STATIC_URL }}` is not loading properly when it is referneced in a coffeescript file that django-compressor compiles to a .js file.

In my django template, I have

```
//this loads fine
{{ STATIC_URL }}
{% load compress %}
{% compress js %}

//STATIC_URL in here does not load
<script type="text/coffeescript" charset="utf-8" src="/static/stuff.coffee" />  

{% endcompress %}
```

In `stuff.coffee` I have

```
$('#test').prepend '<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/image.png" />'
```

Then the rendered HTML in the browser is

```
/static/
<img id="theImg" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/image.png">
```

Thus my question is, how do I get Django to recognize the `{{ STATIC_URL }}` in the coffeescript file?  Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `[.js|.coffee]` files are not django templates, and will not be evaluated. Either you need to preprocess your scripts with django's template renderer, or you set the variable in a html template, and assign it to a javascript window property. E.g.:

In your django template:

```
window.staticUrl = "{{ STATIC_URL }}";

{% load compress %}
{% compress js %}

//STATIC_URL in here does not load
<script type="text/coffeescript" charset="utf-8" src="/static/stuff.coffee" />  

{% endcompress %}
```

In your `stuff.coffee`:

```
$('#test').prepend "<img src="#{window.staticUrl}images/image.png" />"
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response.  How can I preprocess the scripts with the template render?  I googled but came up short.  This seems like the ideal solution.  I also tried assigning the STATIC_URL to property.  However, it is not getting picked up by the compiled CoffeeScript code.  I think the reason is that window.staticUrl can't replace parts of the CoffeeScript code after it has already been compiled.

Comment: It hit me that the string was quoted in `'`, which means that CS `#{}`-style placeholders will not be evaluated. Now, it should work. The `staticUrl` property will be evaluated when you issue the `prepend` call.

I'm not sure what kind of trickery would be required to do the preprocessing first.

Comment: Thanks it worked!  Does js interpret the `'` and `"` differently?

Comment: @AlexisK: No, it's a coffeescript thing, not a javascript thing. CS will expand `"Hello #{foo}"` to `"Hello " + foo`. But only in double-quotes. Single-quoted strings like `'Hello #{foo}'` are literal. See http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#strings

Comment: thanks.  Ahhh it is a coffescript thing.  Very cool.  Thanks again for the help.